# Open source admin/monitoring tool for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Need to know if there is free open source tool for monitoring a cassandra cluster?
- metrics
- user mgmt
- back up / restore
- nodetool stuff

Is DSE Ops center a freely available tool?

thanks
Bhupen

Answer (score 3):

I use jolokia-agent + telegraf with influxdb and Grafana to monitor my cluster.

I wrote a post about it here:

https://andreastech.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/cassandra-performance-monitoring-by-using-jolokia-agent-telegraf-influxdb-and-grafana/

Comment: Trying to setup Grafana/InfluxDB/Jolokia/telegraph framwework for cassandra monitoring. I get Error parsing /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf, line 571: field corresponding to `metrics' is not defined in `*system.SystemStats' while testing the telegraf.conf itself. I am following your blog step by step ...

Comment: Can you share what is in your telegraf.conf around line 571?
Probably caused by some uncommented line in your conf, e.g. check:  [[inputs.cassandra]]

Comment: Yes it was the COMMENTING issue. Thanks for the help.. I wasted 3 hours on this ...-(

Comment: Will test the grafana part now ... will come back to you for help

Comment: UBUNTU 16.04. 1. my 3 node cassandra cluster is perfectly working. 2. Installed jolokia and telegraf on one of the node. 2. sudo service telegraf start (no log can be seen in /var/log though) 3. another ubuntu node has influxDB. telegraf connects OK to influxDB. Added "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Client,name=connectedNativeClientsname=*". restarted the telegraf. Not seeing the series called "cassandraClient" in the influxDB. what could be missing?

Comment: First thing: your config line does not match to mine, it should be: 
 "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Client,name=connectedNativeClients"
You can check telegraf by sudo service telegraf status - it will print the last few lines of the logs and based on that you should be able to verify if telegraf working properly. 

Don't forget to edit the cassandra-env.sh (see 2. step at the Jolokia agent section)
 
echo 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia-1.4.0/agents/jolokia-jvm.jar"' >> /etc/conf/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh and then restart cassandra.

Comment: Hi ... I added "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Client,name=connectedNativeClientsname=*" and restarted telegraf but it does not create series called 'cassandraClient".. show series shows > show series
key
---
cpu,cpu=cpu-total,host=csnvm1
cpu,cpu=cpu0,host=csnvm1
disk,fstype=ext4,host=csnvm1,path=/
diskio,host=csnvm1,name=sda
diskio,host=csnvm1,name=sda1
kernel,host=csnvm1
mem,host=csnvm1
processes,host=csnvm1
swap,host=csnvm1
system,host=csnvm1.... looks like telegraf and jolokia are working and are able to pull some data from cassandra

Comment: Have you also updated the cassandra-env.sh an restarted Cassandra afterwards?

Comment: Yes I hav updated the cassandra. I also added the IP JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/home/cassandra/jolokia/jolokia-1.5.0/agents/jolokia-jvm.jar=port=8778,host=10.142.0.4". Apart from this the metrics had IP mentioned in the server settings section of telegraf.conf which I changed to DNS names. then it started pushing data in influxdb for the cassandra JMX read drivers

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prometheus+Grafana for some of these needs (various monitoring tasks).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage the nodes using DSE Opscentre and it is a free tool provided by datastax. In ops centre, you can know the status of every node and the load, write and read latencies, queries that included allow filtering, and manage schema and other stuff.

Comment: Opscenter not a free tool and is available only with DSE Enterprise

Comment: It is a free tool(as far as i know) and we can import normal apache nodes also to monitor them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DSE Ops center for Apache Cassandra 2.1 and less.

Answer (score 0):

**Opscenter**

Starting with Opscenter version 6.0, OpsCenter is no longer compatible with Apache Cassandra (the open source version of Cassandra), and is only compatible with Datastax Enterprise Clusters.

See the new [Opscenter Policy Changes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html)

**Open Source Alternatives**

- Monitoring

As an opensource alternative to Opscenter I would suggest as [Valerie Parham-Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296561/5102653) above to use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) as a robust monitoring solution for Cassandra. The JMX exporter can export from a wide variety of JVM-based applications, such as Cassandra.

- Repair Management

To manage repairs (vital to ensure an healthy cluster), as a great alternative to OpsCenter, I suggest using [Cassandra Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/). A tool that makes managing and automating repairs extremely easy and efficient.

I actually prefer Cassandra Reaper to OpsCenter for Repair Management.

- Backup & Restore

For backup and restore you had [Priam](https://github.com/Netflix/Priam) developed by Netflix, but alas, it hasn't seen many updates in the last few years, so I advise against it. Instead develop a custom script for this.